# Like / Unlike Push Notifications issue

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have an app with a like functionality. Each time `user A` likes `content X` of `user B`:

- It creates a notification request in my Firebase Database
- Firebase functions observes the path on write & creates a push notification for `user B`

But when `user A` likes -> unlikes -> likes `content X`, `user B` gets another push notification.

How is it possible to decline further notification requests by `user A` for `content X`?

This is the Firebase Functions code:

```
exports.sendLikeNotification = likeRef.onWrite(event => {

  if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  var notificationId = event.params.likeNotificationId;
  var notificationRequest = event.data.val();
  var receiverId = notificationRequest.receiverId;
  var message = notificationRequest.message
  var data = notificationRequest.data

  var topic = '/topics/user_' + receiverId;

  var payload = {
    notification: {
      body: message,
      sound: 'default'
    },
    data: { data }
  };

  var options = {
    priority: "high",
    contentAvailable: true
  };

  // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      return event.data.adminRef.remove();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
  });
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have to maintain a flag in your database to check weather it's a fresh first like or not. Based on that flag you can decide weather to send a notification or not.

Comment: If you're trying to only notify any user once for an action by user A on content X, then the only way to know that is to keep track of which notifications you've already sent for each piece of content for each user.  So, when user A causes a notification about content X, you have to add that to your database (probably a list of contents that user A has notified) and the next time user A modifies something, you check to see if that user has already caused a notification for that piece of content.  If not, you add it to the list and send the notification.  If yes, you skip the notification.

Comment: You have a database choice whether you keep a list of users who've notified for each piece of content or keep track of which pieces of content each user has notified about.  The latter makes it simpler if you ever want to remove users from your system because you can just delete the user object and all their notification records go with it.